# Обновление программы Delphi, которая следит, что пользователь ничего не делает в Modal окне

Tags: delphi, обновление

Пишу обновлялку на Delphi

Для этого у меня есть 2 формы - Main и UpdateProgram. msi файл создан с помощью Wix#

Main:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FUpdateForm := TfrmUpdateProgram.Create(self);
...
end;
```

UpdateProgram:

```
procedure TfrmUpdateProgram.tmrCheckUpdateTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  installer : Variant;
  database : Variant;
  sql : String;
  view : Variant;
  rec : Variant;
begin
  tmrCheckUpdate.Enabled := False;
  var MsiFileName := 'testpath/test.msi';     //Test

  CoInitialize(nil);
  try
    installer := CreateOleObject('WindowsInstaller.Installer');
    database := installer.OpenDatabase( MsiFileName, 0 );
    sql := 'SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property = ''ProductVersion''';
    view := database.OpenView(sql);
    view.Execute();
    rec := view.Fetch();
    var string_variable := rec.StringData[1];
    var a := False; //string_variable =  TProgramVersion.GetProgramVersion.ToString;
      if (not a) and (GetParentForm(self).Enabled) then
      begin
        self.ShowModal;
      end;
  finally
    rec := Unassigned;
    view:= Unassigned;
    database := Unassigned;
    installer := Unassigned;
  end;
  tmrCheckUpdate.Enabled := True;
end;
```

В итоге по таймеру выскакивает окно, когда находит новое обновление

[image: Окно обновления]

Моя проблема в том, что в Main иногда вызываются модальные окна, в них есть необходимая работа, которая требует завершение выполнения до конца. Так как таймер работает многопоточно, то при работе с модальным окном данная обновлялка вылезает и не дает завершить работу

Есть ли способы отлавливать, есть ли модальные окна у формы? (Не хочу писать event на каждое открытие модального окна, тк слишком много дописывать)

Если нет, то кроме как добавить кнопку "Отложить обновление" есть еще варианты решения данной проблемы?

Comment: Я считаю, что подход в принципе не верен. Обновлялка пусть работает в любом потоке и выводить окно с сообщением нужно не в модальном режиме. Выведите сообщение во всплывающем окне уведомлений или строкой в строке статуса или еще как-то так. Пользователь увидит и отреагирует после завершения критичного участка работы. Как вариант оповещение сделать так, а обновление только на старте программы.

Comment: К сожалению, нужно принудительно обновлять, так как иначе работники не будут обновлять данную программу. А так, да. По концепции, я с вами согласен

Comment: Принудительное обновление на старте программы

Comment: Это тоже один из вариантов. Сейчас как раз так наша программа и работает :). Но нам не нравится оповещать всех, чтобы перезапустили программу

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно ориентироваться на свойство [TApplication.ModalLevel](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ModalLevel) - показывает количество открытых в данный момент модальных окон.